# Why can't this top-level Groovy class be static?

Tags: groovy

**Question**

Example 1 without the `static` keyword works.

Example 2 with the `static` keyword does not work.

Why can't the top-level class `StaticClass` be `static`? Eclipse says:

> Groovy:The class 'StaticClass' has an incorrect modifier static.

The class `StaticInnerClass` can be modified as `static`.

**Example 1 works**

Start.groovy

```
assert "static field" == StaticClass.StaticInnerClass.staticField
```

StaticClass.groovy

```
class StaticClass { // Just "class", no "static" modifier
    static class StaticInnerClass {
        static String staticField = "static field"
    }
}
```

**Example 2 does not work**

Start.groovy

```
assert "static field" == StaticClass.StaticInnerClass.staticField
```

StaticClass.groovy

```
static class StaticClass { // Modifier "static" does not work
    static class StaticInnerClass {
        static String staticField = "static field"
    }
}
```

**Possibly related question**

[groovy static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848971/groovy-static-class?rq=1)

**Versions**

- Eclipse 3.8.1
- Groovy-Eclipse plugin 2.8.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only nested classes can be static (just like in Java).

If you just don't want your class to be instantiable, you can qualify the individual definitions in a class with the static keyword, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {

  static public count = 1

  static incr() {
    count = count + 23
  }
}
```

Comment: You can still instantiate that class.